# Postrgresql query slow only fromn pg_query of PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm doing a query from PHP to PostgreSQL and it's extremely slow.
The query is the `SELECT *, CAST(data->>'created_at' as timestamp) as fecha FROM gorda_lipo.tweets WHERE idusuario = 125379829  LIMIT 20`

On PHPpgadmin it tooks only 21.172 ms, but if I try to do the query on PHP with  `pg_query(the connection, the query)` the query is canceled because of timeout, and if I try to manually cancel it using `SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid);` it takes more than one minute.

If I make another query 
`SELECT *, CAST(data->>'created_at' as date) as fecha,CAST(data->>'id' as BIGINT) as idusuario  FROM gorda_lipo.usuarios WHERE CAST(data->>'id' as BIGINT) = (SELECT *from (SELECT CAST(data->>'id' as BIGINT) FROM gorda_lipo.usuarios LIMIT 50) t ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1)`

It works fine. I pretend to use the result for the idusuario of the first query, but it doens't work even if I use a number instead.

Why is the query so slow on PHP with pg_query ? What am I doing wrong? 
Is there another plugin to use?

Comment: It depends on how you do fetch the results. If you do `fetchAll()`, then all the results have to be stored in memory prior to being output.

Comment: I use pg_fetch_array to fetch line by line

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at php.ini's max_execution_time value. There's no reason to your query be slower when querying from PHP, you probably are trying to display all data at once.

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Well, I used limit 1 and I could get some results, but it got frozen on some lines. I'm suspecting that it's slow when the result line is too large...

Comment: Since you are using pg_fetch_array, results are stored in memory. And you are writing all the results in the screen, this is what makes your browser freeze sometimes. You should paginate your results, the you will not have a large data amount in memory and it will be easier to write to screen.